# Autofill with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to autofill using a macro but it doesnt work... Will only fill H2 and I2 cells, the rest are blank. Whats wrong with my code?

```
Sub company()
Dim LastRow As Long
    With Sheets("Combined")
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("H2:H" & LastRow).Value = 0
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Value = 1
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If in column H only H2 is filled then LastRow will be 2.

Comment: Where do you want your data to fill down to? Additionally, is there a reason you're using `.Value2` over `.Value`? Lastly - no need to wrap 0 and 1 in quotation marks, unless you want them to be interpreted as a text for whatever reason.

Comment: @dwirony, The last cell is changing with different worksheets, so that is why I do not have an end cell.

Comment: You are counting the rows in column H before you fill them, so it will always fill only up to H2. get `lastRow` from another column instead of the one you're populating.

Comment: @FernandoJ.Rivera How would i go about doing that? so add another row, input data then delete old row? I need the data to be in H and I

Comment: How do you know which row to stop in? Do you have data in other columns? If you have a full column of data in Col A (for example) change `Cells(Rows.Count, "H"` for `Cells(Rows.Count, "A"`

Comment: @FernandoJ.Rivera oh, yes! I'm sorry I misunderstood your question. Yes, I do have data in other columns! Let me try that

Comment: @FernandoJ.Rivera It worked! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Going to be pedantic now... that's not really an autofill.  `.Range("I1").AutoFill .Range("I1:I" & LastRow)` would be an autofill (gives the same result though based on a single number).